# How to autoload Composer packages in CakePHP 2 Travis integration

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, travis-ci, cakephp-2.x

I'm working on a CakePHP 2.x plugin that uses Composer to pull in a package dependency. I am now trying to use the Friends of Cake's [Travis package](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/travis) to automatically run my unit tests whenever the plugin's repository is updated.

As far as I can tell this does not include the Composer autoload file required for loading in my vendor files. As a result my tests fail as the class defined in the third-party package is missing.

As described in [CakePHP 2's advanced installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html) I'm trying to add the following to `bootstrap.php`:-

```
require APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';
```

I've attempted to do this via the `before_script` of my `.travis.yml` file to append `bootstrap.php`:-

```
before_script:
  - git clone https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/travis.git --depth 1 ../travis
  - ../travis/before_script.sh
  - echo "require APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';" >> ../cakephp/app/Config/bootstrap.php
```

Unfortunately this is failing as the file `APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php'` cannot be found. (I have also tried looking for the file in `APP . '..' . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php'`).

Where is the Composer `autoload.php` file located when installing CakePHP using Travis? How can I ensure my third-party package is loaded when my tests run remotely on Travis CI?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's using the default composer vendor directory, which is `./vendor/autoload.php` (lowercase vendor, top directory). In Cake 2, all vendor files where within the app structure under Vendor, and the first bit in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer) about the composer file changes composer's vendor directory, which the FOC travis installer doesn't do for you. You may be able to edit the directory to what Cake expects by adding `composer config vendor-dir "Vendor/"` in your before_script block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the `Vendor` folder in the `require` statement to the lowercase `vendor` in the `before_script`:-

```
before_script:
  - git clone https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/travis.git --depth 1 ../travis
  - ../travis/before_script.sh
  - echo "require APP . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';" >> ../cakephp/app/Config/bootstrap.php
```

After doing this CakePHP correctly includes the Composer autoload file.

Answer (score 3):

Default directory name for third party plugins is `vendor` (lower case), CakePHP have `Vendor`, you can change that in `.../app/composer.json`

```
{
   "config": {
      "vendor-dir": "Vendor" // CakePHP third party plugins dir name
   },
   "require": {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. I made it work this way.